# Perl Regex match and replace

Tags: regex, perl

I try insert new line after **< /a>**

```
I tried this 
perl -pe '/<\/a> $&\n /g' teste.txt
```

Example

```
Source code
<a href="/link/">link</a><a href="/link2/">link2</a>
```

Output

```
<a href="/link/">link</a>
<a href="/link2/">link2</a>
```

Comment: And what is the issue??

Comment: You seem to be missing the `s///` command in your script.

Comment: not work my code ...

Comment: where put s/// ?

Comment: It should be the whole script. `s` is for performing replacement of a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `s` command to perform regexp replacement.

```
perl -pe 's/<\/a>/$&\n /g' teste.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A plain `/xxx/` will just perform a match, you need `s/xxx/yyy/` to perform a single replacement, and a `s/xxx/yyy/g` to perform multiple replacements.  You may also replace the `/` with another character such as `|` so you do not need to escape any characters, which makes it more readable.

```
perl -pe 's|</a>|$&\n|g;' teste.txt
```

Have a look at [perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a gentle introduction to perl regular expressions.